# Cannot read data from HttpListener .NET

Tags: c#, .net, http, httplistener

I am stuck with reading data from HttpListener. Data arrives, I verify it with `request.ContentLength64` that is usually over 8000 and it increases as the server generates more and more data.
The server sends data as HTTP post and the content type is text/plain.
When I try to check whether streamreader got some data via its length attribute I get 0.
The code is a little bit messy as I was trying different ways to make it work but unfortunatelly I had no luck.
Does anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
                HttpListener listener2 = new HttpListener();
                listener2.Prefixes.Clear();
                listener2.Prefixes.Add("http://+:4200/");
                listener2.Prefixes.Add("http://XXX.XXX.eu/");

                listener2.Start();
                LogWriteLine("http listener started listening to: " +listener2.Prefixes);

                try
                {
                    while (true)//change to match end check
                    {
                        LogWriteLine("http listener waiting");
                        HttpListenerContext context = listener2.GetContext();
                        LogWriteLine("http request arrived");
                        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
                        // Obtain a response object.
                        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

                        System.IO.Stream body = request.InputStream;
                        System.Text.Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
                        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, encoding);


                        if (!request.HasEntityBody)
                        {
                            LogWriteLine("No client data was sent with the request.");
                            Thread.Sleep(300);
                            //return;
                        }

                        if (request.ContentType != null)
                        {
                            LogWriteLine("Client data content type " + request.ContentType);
                        }
                        LogWriteLine("Client data content length " + request.ContentLength64); //Works fine

                        LogWriteLine("Start of client data:");
                        // Convert the data to a string and display it on the console.

                        Console.WriteLine(body.CanSeek);


                        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var ahoj = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine("ahoj length " + ahoj.Length); //0
                        Console.WriteLine(s); //nothing

                        string text;
                        var bytes = default(byte[]);
                        using (var reader1 = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,
                                 request.ContentEncoding))
                        {
                            text = reader1.ReadToEnd();
                            Console.WriteLine(text + text.Length); //output: 0
                            using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                reader1.BaseStream.CopyTo(memstream);
                                bytes = memstream.ToArray();
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("bytes:" + bytes.Length); //output: bytes: 0

                        }



                        LogWriteLine("End of client data:");
                        //write to console file
                        sw.Write(s);
                        body.Close();
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);

                }
```

Comment: Try setting memory stream position to zero before reading.  The CopyTo is leaving the position of the memory stream at end location.  When you read from the End location you do not get any data. You have to read from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunatelly setting memstream.Position = 0; made no difference, still getting "bytes: 0". I am really out of ideas :(

Comment: Also if I try memstream.Length I get 0. I really think there is an error when transfering the Input stream to reader. But dunno how to fix it, since I found just this kind of methods on the Internet.

Comment: Okay, it kinda worked, not as intended though, but I can work with that. When I did memstream.Position = 0; I got no data printed out, but when I checked log (sw.Write(s);), all the data was there. How is it possible that setting position of memstream to zero (I suppose that memstream gets data from reader1 and not vice versa) makes streamwriter work? I just don't get how are these two connected :D

Comment: What is the status of the response?  200 OK or something else?  Does the body contain data?  If you are in chunk mode (http 1.1) and getting 100 continue you are not getting the entire response.

Comment: The bytes length will be zero : bytes = memstream.ToArray() when you do not set position to zero.